# Excel VBA: Declared variable references itself, why?

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I am currently working through the 'Excel 2019 VBA Full Course Tutorial (7+ Hours)' YouTube training course by LearnIT Training, which I highly recommend it (find link below). I have understood most of it so far but the code attached (time stamp - 3:05:50 to 3:08:50) is not very clear to me.

Can somebody assist me in understanding why the File variable, after already being defined, is then redefined using itself?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZ4pBe_MHQ8&t=11425s

```
File = InputBox("What is the name of the new vehicles file?", _
    "New vehicles file name?", _
    "Received Vehicles.xlsx")
File = FileLocation & "\"& File
```

Comment: Likely because the code author actually cared about the full filepath, not just the filename.

Comment: You may see the code to open Excel file like `Set objWB = Workbooks.Open(File)` in training sample file. `FileLocation` is necessary to locate `Received Vehicles.xlsx` (or other user input).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from a bigger object like a workbook, I haven't seen any variable not being used by itself.

The following ones are all correct (with example results explained):

```vb
rCounter = rCounter + 1                'rCounter was 1, is now 2
a = a & b                              'a was "Yes" and is now "YesNo"
Set rng = rng.Offset(1)                'the same range but one row further
Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:= ws) 'ws is now the newly added sheet
```

And in your case
`File = FileLocation & "\"& File`
FileLocation was likely something like `C:\User\You\Test\`
to which you'd want to add the filename which is currently saved in `File` to open the File (I'm guessing, I didn't watch the video) so then you need to add them together to get the full filepath as Big Ben said.

Comment: Thanks Notus_Panda, I think that answers my question.